# MySQL - Link two elements from the same table in another table

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have created a table in MySQL, and i would like to make connections between those elements.

It should be a many-to-many relationship, and what i've come up with is the following:

- Create a table with the elements:

  table Medicine

  **| id | name | description |**
- Create a table with the links:

  table Incompatibilities

  **| medicine_id_1 | medicine_id_2 |**

So when i want to create an incompatibility between medicine 1 and medicine 2, i should do:

```
INSERT INTO incompatibilities VALUES 1,2
```

And when i would like to retrieve all the medicine that are incompatible with medicine ID = 1 i should do:

```
SELECT * FROM incompatibilities WHERE medicine_id_1=1 OR medicine_id_2=1
```

Is this the correct way to do it? Are those queries work as intended? Is there a more efficient way to do what i am after?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 7):

Since incompatibility is a symmetric irreflexive relationship, you should always store the medicines in order: that with a least id in `medicine_id_1`, that with the greatest id in `medicine_id_2`.

You should create the unique indexes:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ux_incompatibility_1_2 ON (medicine_id_1, medicine_id_2)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ux_incompatibility_2_1 ON (medicine_id_2, medicine_id_1)
```

, insert the values:

```
INSERT
INTO    incompatibility (medicine_id_1, medicine_id_2)
VALUES   (LEAST(@med1, @med2), GREATEST(@med1, @med2))
```

This way, you store the relationships in both ways within a single record, and the `UNIQUE` constraints work properly.

To select all incompatible medicines:

```
SELECT  CASE 1 WHEN medicine_id_1 THEN medicine_id_2 ELSE medicine_id_1 END
FROM    incompatibility
WHERE   medicine_id_1 = 1
        OR medicine_id_2 = 1
```